# Where can I source my own food safe pizza steel?

Tags: equipment, pizza

I am looking to save some money and order a slab of scrap steel from a local company. 
My question is what kind of steel should I be asking for to ensure the steel is food grade quality?

Comment: As long as it hasn't been used as a container of some toxic material it'll be fine. Cast iron pans are made from recycled disk brakes and nobody has any problems with them at all.

Comment: I've just made one from aluminium, but it takes a lot of semolina to stop the pizza sticking to it. https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/10527/1344 should soon have a picture

Answer (score 2):

Most people recommend A36 steel, which is a fairly common low-carbon steel.  As far as I understand it (procured mine through ebay), you just need to work at scraping off the [mill scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_scale) with some abrasive.  Wash, dry, then season like a cast iron pan.  After that you should be good to go.